# how to show YOY metric values as text in a tableau viz

Tags: tableau-desktop

[please click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0VMp.png)

2 questions to the Tableau Sanseis:

The given percentages/numbers in the attachment (shown by parentheses), all belong to the YOY variance and are meant to be displayed in front of the orange (2021) bars

a) Both the numbers/percentages are not showing in one line and current display gives the impression to a user that %ages belong to the blue bars and number to the orange colored bars.
- How to show both in front of orange bars ?

b) Beats me as to why some of the category bars (highlighted with red arrows) don't display any value (no %ages or numbers)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably "between" your two measure there's some CR, so you see one up and the other down, causing to display just some values and not all.

Something like this:
[image]

Go into the Text Mark of your worksheet, and try to dispay your values in just one line with no CR, and you should get something like this:

[image]

Sometimes, due to font size and cardinality of your data, some label could be missing just because Tableau tries to optimize the rendering, but you can also check the last option of the Label Mark selecting "Allow Labels to overlap other marks".